# How can we write something like unit tests for testing Azure policies without actually creating resources?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-policy, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am currently working on a project where the goal is to test Azure policies before deploying them, the closest I came across this article [https://charotamine.medium.com/azure-policy-what-if-you-test-your-policies-5ddb12c95a07](https://stackoverflow.com) but here too resources are created.

I am wondering if there is some library which takes policy.json and the resource.json as input and runs the policy analysis against the resource.json file. For testing a single policy.json I will create multiple resource.json files, each resource.json file for a specific test case (like a unit test function for a class)

I have tried reading the Python azure sdk for anything that can be of help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can can use the below "frameworks".
They are *"an automated testing approach for Azure Policies. The approach is fundamentally based on behavior-driven development (BDD)"*.

https://github.com/fawohlsc/azure-policy-testing
or
https://github.com/Azure/Enterprise-Scale/wiki/ALZ-Policies-Testing (built on the first)

Comment: Hello
thank you so much for replying back , the problem with this approach is we have to create heavy resources when testing the policies am looking for a approach where we can achieve testing without incurring the overhead of creating resources.

Comment: @ChinmayPawar doubtful that is currently possible. The policy is interacting with ARM, so you would somehow have to manipulate that interaction. Read more about testing here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/evaluate-impact